# Eliminate ghost margin below HTML5 canvas element?

Tags: css, html, html5-canvas

When we create an HTML5 canvas element, a ghost margin appears below the canvas element even though we set the margin and padding to 0.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/yvbmd/

We tried a variety of things, but can't erase the ghost margin.

How can we create the canvas element without that ghost margin?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: bottom` to it.

This is caused by the canvas being an inline element. As such, it is effectively considered a character. As such, it must follow the baseline rule, which is to leave a little space below the line in case of characters such as `gjpqy` which drop below the baseline. By setting the `vertical-align` to `bottom`, you are actually aligning the canvas to the bottom of the drop-down letters. So long as the canvas itself is taller than the `line-height`, you will have no problems. Should the canvas be shorter than the `line-height`, you will start seeing "ghost margins" above the canvas as it reserves room for `bdfhklt`, the taller letters. This can be fixed by adding a `line-height: 1px` rule.

Comment: Thanks, Kolink! Because of your insight, we solved this by making the canvas element a block element with "display:block." Do you see any problems with this solution?

Comment: Well, it's **a** solution. It depends on what you're using the canvas for, really.