# Removing space below canvas when within li

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eliminate ghost margin below HTML5 canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878090/eliminate-ghost-margin-below-html5-canvas-element)

My DOM resembles:

```
<ul>
  <li><canvas width="200" height="300" /></li>
</ul>
```

You can [see it in the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/EjuuW/2/).

Even though I've set all margin and padding values to zero, there's still a hanging space between the bottom of the `canvas` and the bottom of the `li`. I've tried many things to remove it, and am obviously missing something.

The behaviour is identical between Chrome 22, Firefox 15 and IE 9, so it doesn't seem like a glitch.

What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878090/eliminate-ghost-margin-below-html5-canvas-element) can help?

Comment: On Chrome it goes away when giving the `li` and `canvas` both `display: block`. I don't know why, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align:top` to the canvas will fix it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EjuuW/6/)**